# How to call a function after promise

Tags: javascript, spfx

JavaScript noobie here. Lacking knowledge of an important design pattern.

this.getEventData(); < How can I call that function after the promise is resolved? So then I can remove the noobie setTimeout ?

```
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
        this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
          .getClient(APIAppRegID)
          .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
            this.httpClient = client;
            resolve();
          }, err => reject(err));
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.getEventData();
      }, 1500);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does _"after the promise"_ mean? After the promise is resolved? The function is called after the promise is created.

Comment: @jabaa Yes thats it

Comment: I'd recommend that you learn how promises work by reading ["Using Promises"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) on MDN.

Comment: Why do you even create a `new Promise`? You are not using it. You can remove the whole promise part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async/await` version :

```
async onInit(): Promise<void> {
  await super.onInit();
  this.httpClient = await this.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient(APIAppRegID);
  this.getEventData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ser!!!

Answer (score 1):

The promise doesn't make any sense. You are not using it. You can remove it:

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
  return super.onInit().then(_ => {
    this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
      .getClient(APIAppRegID)
      .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
        this.httpClient = client;
        this.getEventData();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, you're right. I moved it into the callback.